# Make radio button appear as buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have a options menu and each option decides what content should be appeared. The solution I have decided, based on UX and UI, is show a group of radio buttons and make them appear as buttons. The color of the button becomes purple when a user selects an option and previously selected button becomes gray, and finally the content changes accordingly. I am using WPF XAML, and using button's style template for radio button.

The problem I am facing is that radio button's IsChecked property never becomes true when any button (which is radio button originally) is clicked. Please help me solve this issue. Following is the code:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                    <Button Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2F2FEA" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

and then the radio button is added as follows:

```
<RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource ButtonRadioButtonStyle}" GroupName="modules" Height="40.64" Content="Materials" Margin="0,184.916,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioButton_Checked" Click="RadioButton_Click"/>
```

When I do the following in click event of radio button:

```
private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton a = sender as RadioButton;

        MessageBox.Show(a.IsChecked.ToString());
    }
```

I always get false displayed. Also radio button's Checked event nevers called.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the `Button` in the style is preventing the `IsChecked` property to be toggled. But here's something that may help you: a `RadioButton` is a type of `ToggleButton`, and the `ToggleButton` looks like a regular `Button`. You can therefore use the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonRadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2F2FEA" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The only issue remaining is that the background color of the `ToggleButton` doesn't change to purple, but this is unrelated to making a radio button look like a button. The problem is that a button's style is fairly complex and more styling is required to change its background properly (see [Changing a WPF Button Background](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Changing-a-WPF-Button-212386c6) for a solution).